# Illegal instance declaration in Haskell

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors, typeclass

I tried the following code

```
class Group a where
  (.+.) :: a -> a -> a
  (.-.) :: a -> a -> a
  zero :: a
  opposite :: a -> a

  x .-. y = x .+. opposite y
  opposite x = zero .-. x
  {-# MINIMAL (.+.), zero, (opposite | (.-.)) #-}

instance Fractional a => Group a where
  x .+. y = x + y
  zero = 0 :: a
  opposite = negate :: a -> a
```

But on loading into GHCi, I get the following error:

```
group1.hs:11:26: error:
    • Illegal instance declaration for ‘Group a’
        (All instance types must be of the form (T a1 ... an)
         where a1 ... an are *distinct type variables*,
         and each type variable appears at most once in the instance head.
         Use FlexibleInstances if you want to disable this.)
    • In the instance declaration for ‘Group a’
   |
11 | instance Fractional a => Group a where
   |
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can suppress this by adding `{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, UndecidableInstances #-}` at beginning of you file, but it leads to other problem. For example `Could not deduce (Num a1) arising from the literal `0'`. I don't see how is `0` is literal with type `Fractional`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to compile your example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, UndecidableInstances #-}

class Group a where
  (.+.) :: a -> a -> a
  (.-.) :: a -> a -> a
  zero :: a
  opposite :: a -> a

  x .-. y = x .+. opposite y
  opposite x = zero .-. x
  {-# MINIMAL (.+.), zero, (opposite | (.-.)) #-}

-- data Fractional a = Fractional a a

instance (Fractional a, Num a) => Group a where
  x .+. y = x + y
  zero = 0
  opposite = negate
```

- `FlexibleInstances` allow instance of unknown type with constraints. Basically allow `instance X a`
- `UndecidableInstances` we need because we declare that any `a` belong to class `Group` and it could (inevitable?) lead to `a` belong to `Group` thru several different `instance` declarations.

Answer (score 3):

Ah! I have finally understood, what is wrong. In Haskell, a class can be instantiated for an ADT only. So, the only reasonable solution is to declare something as follows:

```
class Group a where
  (.+.) :: a -> a -> a
  (.-.) :: a -> a -> a
  zero :: a
  opposite :: a -> a

  x .-. y = x .+. opposite y
  opposite x = zero .-. x
  {-# MINIMAL (.+.), zero, (opposite | (.-.)) #-}

newtype GroupType a = GroupType a  

instance Fractional a => Group (GroupType a) where
  GroupType x .+. GroupType y = GroupType $ x + y
  zero = GroupType 0
  opposite (GroupType x) = GroupType $ negate x
```

Comment: That's correct. Note that, with extensions on, we can write `instance ... => Group a`. If we do, however, we can never define another instance for `Group` since any other `instance ... => Group (something)` will be overlapping with the first one. (Turning on the "overlapping instances" extension opens a can of worms -- not recommended). If possible, using a `newtype` as you do above is better. It also allow multiple instances for the same type e.g. `instance Group (Additive T)` and `instance Group (Multiplicative T)` which have the same underlying type `T`.